# Is there a way to change the "focus field" on a SharePoint form?

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-form, client

For something we've built, the default new item form contains a publishing HTML field. For some unknown reason, when SharePoint displays this new item form, it drops the cursor into this publishing HTML field. That has consequences for the ribbon.

I need to get SharePoint to drop the cursor on the first field rather than this one. Is there in fact a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have access to edit the page code? Add some JS to the page that holds the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've blogged about this before, this was for 2010, so I'm not sure if it will work for 2013 so you might have to test/adjust but it is a good starting point, http://ericjalexander.com/blog/2013/08/14/Publishing-HTML-Column-Frustrations.

> Lately I’ve been doing a lot of work in the publishing/WCM area and
>   one thing that’s really aggravated me is that when you have a content
>   type created for a page layout Sharepoint tries to be too cutesy when
>   you edit the metadata for the item.
>
> When you try to edit properties of the page, Sharepoint’s awesome UX
>   will find the first Publishing HTML field and set that as the focused
>   item no matter where it is in the content type order. So if it’s the
>   last field in your content type, it steals the focus from the first
>   field. This is horrible UX in that I want to fill my metadata from the
>   top down, that’s precisely why I ordered the columns the way I did.
>
> Another side effect is that if you use Google Chrome and try to select
>   a drop down list value while this field has focus, the drop down will
>   autmatically collapse on you, again poor UX. This Page library is also
>   using modal dialogs because if you don’t, you can’t properly use the
>   rich html tools the field provides in Chrome either.
>
> So I was looking for a fix. I came across a post from [Rob](http://sharepointchronicles.com/2011/11/sharepoint-2010-javascript-quirks/)
>   mentioning this weird behavior but no real mention of a fix. In my
>   Binging I also found this lovely [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.richhtmlfield.hasinitialfocus(v=office.14).aspx) that specifies
>   there is an override for this lovely “feature”. So I have to create a
>   bunch of server side code to fix this poor UX? Surely there has to be
>   a better option.
>
> Since this editform already has some jQuery on it for other
>   enhancements I thought I’d be able to fix this straight away no
>   problem. Tried the typical document.ready things like
>   `$("input[Title='Title']").click()` and
>   `$("input[Title='Title']").focus()` to no avail. Turns out this
>   information is loaded asynchronously. Yippee, time to dig around in
>   the SOD javascript files.
>
> After parusing through some of the on demand files and some trial and
>   error, I finally came up with a hacky fix to get the focus out of the
>   publishing html field and back up to the top of my form. Put this into
>   a script tag:
>
> ```
> function waitUnitStuffIsLoaded() {
>   setTimeout(function(){refocus()},1000);
> }
>
> function refocus(){
>   $("input[Title='Title']").focus();
> }
>
> SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(waitUnitStuffIsLoaded, "sp.ui.spellcheck.js");
> ```
>
> I tried a lot of the js files that were loaded
>   on demand, like ribbon.js and this was the only one I found that
>   worked.

Comment: Eric, it worked! The field title (as it turns out) is "Title Required Field", but that's no problem considering the code is in a page-local script editor. It still doesn't solve the problem of the disappearing ribbon, but hey, one problem at a time. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added some JS:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changeInitialFocus");

function changeInitialFocus() {
    WPQ2FormCtx.InitialFocus = null;
    SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.RegisterClientForm('WPQ2');
    var form = SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.GetClientForm('WPQ2');
    if (form != null) form.RenderClientForm();
}
```

Set

```
WPQ2FormCtx.InitialFocus
```

To the initial FieldName to get the focus on the desired field. With the value

```
null
```

no field has a focus and the view stays at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to focus on any other field instead just avoid focusing on anything. Like I'm using SharePoint 2013 and have rich html fields in page layout, I didn't want the focus on anything; just to show the start of the page as is..

For this I override the existing method in `sp.ui.rte.publishing.js` file as follows:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.ui.rte.publishing.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
   RTE.Canvas.initialFocusOnRichText = function () { };
});
```

It stopped the focus on rich html field.

I didn't find any console errors or undesired behavior in rich html field after adding this, however if someone notice please do comment.